# Using X3D and Javascript

Tags: x3d

I'm supposed to develop a project using X3D. I have an idea to create a conversor of DXf file to X3D. however, to do that, I have to use Javascript to manage this properly, but  I haven't found a way to integrate Javascript with X3D. Does someone know some way to do that?
Previously, I though in loading the dxf file, get the data I need, and save this as a X3D file, like writing the XML.

thanks in advance

Comment: You should always try to find something yourself before asking a question!

Comment: Yes, Philip G, I know it. I've been searching for this. I just asked to know if it is possible or not and if someone could help me to focus on a good way to find this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X3D supports JavaScript natively in the Script node (and it is sometimes referred to via the standardization name EcmaScript).  Script events are connected to a scene via ROUTE statements.  This provides a bridge between declarative 3D models and programmatic events/computation.  Lots more online:

- http://x3dgraphics.com/examples/X3dForWebAuthors/Chapter09EventUtilitiesScripting
- http://www.web3d.org/x3d/content/examples/Vrml2Sourcebook/Chapter30Scripts
- http://www.web3d.org/x3d/content/examples/X3dSceneAuthoringHints.html#Scripts
- http://www.web3d.org/x3d/content/X3dTooltips.html#Script
- http://www.web3d.org/documents/specifications/19775-1/V3.3/Part01/components/scripting.html#Script

Answer (score 0):

In VRML you can integrate javascript using the `Script` node.
Here's an example:

```
DEF SCRIPT Script {
   url ["javascript:
         here goes your javascript code
     "]
}
```

Considering that X3D started as the XML representation of VRML then I suppose there is support in X3D for the `Script` node.

Edit: Yes I can [confirm the above](http://www.web3d.org/documents/specifications/19775-1/V3.2/Part01/components/scripting.html).